# this.isRTL is not a function error when using paper-dropdown-menu webcomponent

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

Getting this error when loading up the paper-dropdown-menu webcomponent.

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._isRTL is not a function
```

Longer stacktrace for SEO:

> Uncaught TypeError: this._isRTL is not a
>   function get _localeHorizontalAlign @
>   iron-dropdown.html:306_updateOverlayPosition @
>   iron-dropdown.html:461_positionTargetChanged @
>   iron-dropdown.html:405_observerEffect @
>   polymer.html:1562_effectEffects @ polymer.html:1405_propertySetter @
>   polymer.html:1389setter @ polymer.html:1468attached @
>   iron-fit-behavior.html:222_invokeBehavior @
>   polymer-micro.html:433_doBehavior @ polymer-micro.html:426(anonymous
>   function) @ polymer-micro.html:210_makeReady @
>   polymer-micro.html:111(anonymous function) @ polymer-micro.html:117
>   polymer-mini.html:2046 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getWidth' of undefined(anonymous function) @
>   app-drawer-layout.html:189complete @
>   polymer-mini.html:2085Debouncer.boundComplete @
>   polymer-mini.html:2062_atEndOfMicrotask @
>   polymer-mini.html:2040window.MutationObserver.observe.characterData @
>   polymer-mini.html:2055

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem now. I am using polymer 1.2.3 and paper-material-tags#~1.0.6. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Polymer 1.5 is not compatible with paper-dropdown-menu version ~1.2.1. I had to downgrade to Polymer 1.4 to use the paper-dropdown-menu.

Edit:

The problem was the this component is not compatible with the Shadow DOM.

Comment: I had no problems using that version of `paper-dropdown-menu` with Polymer 1.5.0 (tested Chrome, Safari, and Firefox on OS X El Capitan). [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/beVjZr?editors=1010)

Comment: @tony19 huh... you are right... what the... It wasn't working with 1.5, I downgraded, to 1.4 and it fixed it. Now I reupgraded to 1.5 and it works. What?

Comment: Do you know whether I will be able to use the component with Polymer 1.2.4?

Comment: Also, this error doesn't come up locally, only on our production server.

Comment: @Asgeir, that's odd... I'm not sure what settings your production server might have different. Only things I can suggest are trying to upgrade Polymer and the paper-dropdown-menu dependency. Good luck.